# Where do I connect 2 gauge neutral and ground wires for a subpanel in the main panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I’m installing this 100 amp square D QO subpanel. I’m running 2 gauge stranded wire from a 100 amp feeder breaker to the sub panel main lugs. There is no opening large enough on the neutral bar for the 2 gauge in the main panel. There is an empty lug between the incoming red and black cables just left of the silver wire which I assume is the ground.

There is also a square hole where it looks like a lug could be installed. On the ground bar there’s a big enough hole for a ground but it might be hard to get into. Where do I connect the neutral and ground wire in the main panel?

Comment: *There is an empty lug between the incoming red and black cables just left of the silver wire which i assume is the ground.* Please check your panel installation instructions. Normally that would be the neutral lug, and if not a service panel an accessory ground bar kit indicated on panel cover needs to be obtained.

Answer (score 5):

QO Auxiliary Neutral Lug Kit - the "legs" go in the holes on the bar,

[image: Auxiliary lug]

*[Image Source](https://images.thdstatic.com/productImages/f1a50fa5-35d7-4217-8db7-101c1f907626/svn/square-d-lugs-qo70ancp-64_100.jpg) no endorsement*

Others bolt to the bar.

[image: Bolt on lug for 100A panel]

*[Image Source](https://images.thdstatic.com/productImages/a6d113a6-4e86-44af-95a5-116863ad0d00/svn/square-d-lugs-lk100ancp-44_145.jpg) no endorsement*

Follow the instructions of the one you get, particularly with regard to torque. I believe the latter type is correct for your panel size, but you can check when buying.

Comment: If you bring a picture of the labeling of your panel to an electrical supply house (not a big-box store), they'll make 100% certain you get the right one, and they'll probably also tell you the torque spec if you ask nicely.

Answer (score 4):

2 AWG stranded aluminum is too small for 100A.  It is limited to 90A, and that is a standard breaker size, so you'll need a 90A breaker there.  There is folk "knowledge" that #2 aluminum is 100A wire, but those people are reading the wrong table.  You need table 310.16, and you are in the 75C column because of 110.14(B).

2 AWG copper, which novices often mistakenly buy after hearing aforementioned folk knowledge but not picking up the "aluminum" part, is 120A wire.

Your description of panel terminals fills me with concern.  The supply neutral should be attached to that third lug, I would think.  Neutral and ground bars are not interchangeable.  (In a main panel, grounds are allowed as a guest on the neutral bar).  It would really help if you could add photos of the panel to the question. StackExchange's cookie-based accounts can be confusing, so make sure to either use the same device/browser to add the pic, or register your account to log on from different devices.

Note that any subpanel loads (looking at you, EV charging) must be fully accounted for in the main panel's NEC 220.82 Load Calculation, unless EVEMS or other EMS is used.