How can I bond neutral and ground feeders to a panel which doesn't have large enough bar holes?
My problem is the neutral and ground bars in the main 200 amp panel does not have holes big enough for the neutral wire from the sub-panel.  The person who installed the old panel that I am replacing, separated the neutral wire into 3 smaller holes in the main panel neutral bar.  Is this within code?  If not how do I go about fixing the main neutral bar to accommodate the bigger wire without replacing the main 200 amp panel?

The panel maker should have a lug/fitting that attaches to the neutral bus.  Do you have enough power left over in the main panel for a 100 amps?

The neutral feed normally goes into a special lug at the end of the neutral bar. Pictures would help a lot.

See: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/293823/18078

What make and model is your panel?

No. UL must test and certify all wiring methods in a panel, and they didn't certify the "split strands" trick.
The manufacturer makes lug kits specifically designed for this problem.  For instance the Eaton NL20 for Eaton BR panels, or Square D LK150AN for Square D.
